# Intentionally Make the Database to Error

Tags: oracle, exception

I need to know how to make *Oracle* database to error out. The reason is to try to catch an exception in the `JDBC`.

Calls to the database are invoked via web services that ultimately use `JDBC` calls to the database. So, consumers interface to the whole thing through *SOAP* requests. The majority of requests take `xsd:string` or/and `xsd:date`.

One way, for instance, I'm doing this is to set a character larger than 4000 character in the `WHERE` clause for a `VARCHAR2` field of (`BYTE` 4000). Are there other ways of forcing the database to throw an error?

Comment: Are you running select statements? PL/SQL?

Comment: @PatrickHofman `SELECT` statements are what I am interested at this time.

Comment: Divide `1/0` ;) . Can you give an example?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm invoking calls to the database via web services that ultimately use `JDBC` calls to the database. So, consumers' interface is simply a *SOAP* request. The majority of requests take `xsd:string` or/and `xsd:date`.

Comment: You can create a function that will raise whatever exception you want, i.e. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60325/1

Comment: @A.B.Cade I cannot modify the database. I added a new paragraph to clarify how calls are being made.

Comment: So, do you mean something like sending a wrong date? i.e. `2014-02-30`

Comment: @A.B.Cade Correct, bad data is one way to accomplish this, i.e. malformed `DATE`, large `VARCHAR2`, etc.. Are there others?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't add objects to the database, then you'll need to use an error that can be created in pure SQL. Here are a few options:

- Invalid date (ORA-01839): `select to_date('2/30/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual`
- Invalid number (ORA-01722): `select cast('aaa' as number) from dual`
- Invalid math (ORA-01476): `select 1/0 from dual`
- Invalid identifier (ORA-00904): `select this_doesnt_exist('aaa') from dual`
- Invalid format (ORA-01810): `select to_date('10','mmmmmmmmm') from dual`

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do one of the following:

- Use a procedure like [A.B.Cade proposed](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60325/1);
- Divide `1/0` or any other low-level error.

My option would be 1, with a few modifications:

```
create function raise_custom_error
( error_no number
, message varchar2
)
return number
as
begin
  raise_application_error(error_no, message);
  return 0;
end;
/
```

Use it like this:

```
select case
       when 1=1 /*bad condition*/
       then raise_custom_error(-20163, 'My custom error')
       else 0
       end
from   dual
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick, but as I mentioned in the question, the only venue that the data is passed to the database for processing is through web services. There is no database manipulation involved.